# Robot Pepper Not able to run Android application on Real Pepper

Tags: android, robotics, pepper

1. I have developed an app for pepper using android studio. the app run fine on emulator, but cannot run it on real pepper robot. I have connected real pepper robot through IP, but when I run through android studio cannot find the real pepper robot tablet in the list of devices.
2. From android.aldebaran.com site under connecting to real pepper its say 
   **Developer mode** should be activated.but couldn't find any such option on real pepper

kindly help with above querys folks 
[image]

Comment: Do you have something like a error message?

Comment: nope! when i run through android studio the pop-up window for select development target doesn't show the pepper robot's tablet. though it is mention if we connect to pepper robot we are connect to tablet.

Comment: Is your problem solved now?

Comment: not yet!  it seems with latest reslease it would be possible with above steps. although I've bypass with commands using choregraphe to achive the same

Comment: Is your problem solved now?

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply skip the activation of the developer mode. You need to set the developer mode in the settings of the real pepper tablet. Check out [this](https://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/getting_started/running_application.html#on-a-real-robot) manual.

To show the settings on the tablet follow these instructions ([Source](https://github.com/arlemi/setup-wifi-pepper#connect-peppers-tablet))

- Open a terminal
- Connect to Pepper using SSH (ssh nao@PEPPER_IP, ...)
- Run the followin command

> qicli call ALTabletService._openSettings

-> The Settings menü should now be opened on the tablet.

There should be something like this:
[image: Pepper description]

If you can't do this, you can't go on...

Comment: thats what is mentioned on there site, but in the real robot i don't find these options. i have edit the question and attached screenshot of the setting tab in my pepper robot.

Comment: Referring to the documentation, I think you need to open the tablet settings directly on the tablet of the pepper. I modified my answer to show you how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem and the cause is that Android apps controlling Pepper is only possible when Pepper is running version 2.9, and it looks like you're on 2.5 or earlier.

However, there's no apparent way to upgrade to 2.9 - we had to fight with Softbank support to get a pre-release version installed, and one robot had to be shipped back to get fixed after doing so. Even now, it doesn't appear to support any of the 2.5 Basic Channel activities.

Since ~August last year we have had two robots on differing versions on 2.9 (2.9.0.129 and 2.9.1.36), neither of which have received any updates.

The Aldebaran community forum appears to have been disabled. Though you can get to individual posts from Google, there's no navigation.

The Android plugin and emulator were updated towards the end of last year, and their [Android documentation](https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/index.html) seems to have improved in recent months, so there's hope that something is going on, but it's hard to find anything public.

Answer (score 0):

To activate developer mode on the tablet, you should follow this steps:

1. open a terminal (Putty )
2. add `nao@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` x is your robot ip
3. press 'yes'
4. enter your robot password
5. enter this code: `qicli call ALTabletService._openSettings`
   That code open the tablet setting on the tablet of pepper. Then the procedure is same as smartphone.
   When the setting on the tablet opened follow these steps:
6. Go to 'About tablet'
7. Scroll down to find the Build number, then tap 5 times quickly. You
   should see the toast opes and say that developer mode is activated.
8. Then go to Developer option and activate it.